# Submit MultipleChoiceField in Django with custom multiselect jQuery box

Tags: jquery, html, django, jquery-ui-multiselect, multiplechoicefield

I am trying to submit a multiple choice field using [this](http://crlcu.github.io/multiselect/examples/search.html) jQuery plugin to render the multiple choices.

My form is as follows:

```
class BackupForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(BackupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contas_choice'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=get_backup_choices(self.user)
        )

        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', })

        self.fields['contas_choice'].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                'name': 'from[]',
                'id': 'search',
                'class': 'form-control',
                'size': '8',
                'multiple': 'multiple',
            }
        )

    contas_choice = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False)
    # other fields
```

And on my template:

```
<form action="" class="form-horizontal" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            {% for choice in form.contas_choice %}
                {{ choice }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button type="button" id="search_rightAll" class="btn btn-block"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="search_rightSelected" class="btn btn-block"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="search_leftSelected" class="btn btn-block"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="search_leftAll" class="btn btn-block"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <select name="to[]" id="search_to" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="actions" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Baixar</button>
            <a href="/listar-contas/" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This renders the select field just like I wanted, as in the example of the plugin reference.

But when I try to submit the form, I get an HTML message saying "**Please select an item in the list**", even after I have moved all the items to the right box. Therefore, I can't submit the form, and I don't even get any Django error, because it fails the HTML validation right away.

What should I do to make all the items on the right box be submitted?

Thanks!

Comment: This problem is hard to reproduce, there could be many reasons that you see this error. Are you sure the page didn't refresh and it's the javascript plugin that gives out this error? A quick way to test this is to use the default django widget and see if it still happens.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @ShangWang. I still haven't made this test, but I see it is indeed a validation problem independent of the javascript plugin. When I manually remove the "required" attribute from the ``<select>`` field, I can submit the form. But, obvious it's not a solution, since the user must select at least one option from the left box.
So the question now is how to validate this properly.